# JQuery remove button from td cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table where user can click to unlock the record. I want to remove Unlock button and replace with the text. For example once they click unlock button will be removed and text will show up like 'Record is unlocked'. I'm not sure why my current code doesn't remove button. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

```js
$('.unlockBtn').on('click',unlockRecord);

function unlockRecord(){
 var trID = $(this).parents("tr").prop('id');
 
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to unlock this record?")){
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'Application.cfc?method=unlockRec',
   data: {'recID':trID},
      dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(obj){
   var numRecs = obj.RECORDCOUNT;
   
   if(obj.STATUS == 200){
    $('#' + trID).closest('.unlockBtn').remove();
   }else{
    alert('Error')
   }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("Error: "+errorThrown);
  });
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="11">
      <td>Jack, Smith</td>
      <td>Active</td>
      <td>12/01/2017</td>
      <td>01:16 PM</td>
      <td class="unlockBtn" style="text-align: center;">
        <input name="unlock" id="unlock" value="Unlock" type="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#' + trID).find('.unlockBtn')` - `find` instead of `closest`

Comment: @tymeJV Can you please explain why .closest() didn't work ?

Comment: `.closest` searches parent elements, while `find` searches child elements. `closest` goes up the DOM tree, `find` goes down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also do you want to remove the actual cell or just replace the contents? I would think what you want to do is first place your click event on the button and not the cell (e.g. `$('.unlockBtn .unlock').on('click',unlockRecord);` then when you want to replace the button with text, you'd remove the event listener and replace the cell contents

```
$('#' + trID)
    .find('input[type="button"]')
        .off()
        .parent('.unlockBtn')
        .html('Record is unlocked');
```

Finally (maybe this is just due to you posting an example, but just in case, if this is a table where the html row shown is duplicated a lot you'll want to change the button id to something that's unique per/row like you do with the table row to avoid conflict

Comment: Since I posted this example with only one record I haven't showed the unique ID's if there is more than one. I use record ID for each button. This way I have unique ID in each row. Yes I just try to replace content of td cell.

Comment: `.off()` just removes event handlers. It's not always necessary as jQuery cleans up a lot for you, but I just always found it a good habit to remove event listeners myself rather than assuming something else is gonna clean up my mess.

Comment: If I remove table row do I still have to remove eventListener ?

Comment: Really it depends on how you remove the row to decide if you _have_ to manually remove the listener. I would recommend you do either way, however using jquery's build in [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) will all do that automatically to avoid memory leaks. However I prefer to cleanup after myself just as a habit.

Answer (score 1):

Just add back your ajax call and you will be done.

```js
$('.unlockBtn').on('click',unlockRecord);

function unlockRecord(){
 var trID = $(this).parents("tr").prop('id');
 
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to unlock this record?")){
  var cell = $(event.srcElement);
    
   $( cell ).replaceWith( "<div>Record Unlocked</div>" );
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="11">
      <td>Jack, Smith</td>
      <td>Active</td>
      <td>12/01/2017</td>
      <td>01:16 PM</td>
      <td class="unlockBtn" style="text-align: center;">
        <input name="unlock" id="unlock" value="Unlock" type="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```